# What concepts should I study to accomplish this?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

I am such a newbie to c# I have to ask questions before I can get started!

What I want to do is enter a numeric number into a text box, send it to an attached sql compact database, check to see if the number is in the table, if true return the data to the form. If false,  I want to run some code that will get the information and update the table, add to table, send to the form. Other then creating sql tables via C#, Could someone help me prototype this concept so to speak so I can start reading up on the concepts so that I can start building this portion of my project? Thanks.

Comment: Can you let us know what is your background? Do you have any other programming experience?

Comment: You have a lot of concepts to learn my young grasshopper.

Comment: As a follow up to my original question, I have read several article stating that Linq to Sql is a great approach to use when working with form apps. Is this still true today, if not which approach should I concentrate on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to do what you are describing.  A quick and easy way to handle this scenario would be to use WPF for the user interface and LINQ to SQL for the database access.  There are tons of tutorials on both technologies, but here are the basic steps:

Step 1: Create a new WPF project in Visual Studio
Step 2: Add a LINQ to SQL class and map it to your Database
Step 3: Edit the MainWindow.xaml and add the input textbox, check button, and results textbox

Sample code for MainWindow.xaml (note this is quick and dirty):

```
<Window x:Class="WPFPlayground.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
            <TextBox Name="InputTextBox" Width="50"/>
            <Button Name="CheckButton" Content="Check DB" Click="CheckButton_Click"/> 
            <TextBox Name="ResultsTextBox" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Step 4: Edit the code behind of MainWindow.xaml.cs to handle the button click event

Sample code for Click event in MainWindow.xaml.cs (again quick and dirty)

```
private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get instance of my LINQ to SQL datacontext
    var db = new MyDbDataContext();

    // Try to get the record that matches the text in the InputTextBox
    var data = db.TableName.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == InputTextBox.Text);

    // Was able to find a matching record so show results data
    if (data != null)
    {
        ResultsTextBox.Text = data.EventDesc;
    }
    else 
    {
        // do what ever you need to do when there is no match
    }
}
```

Step 5: Learn some best practices and do not use this sample code :)

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

I'd head over to the MS [Development for Beginners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/default.aspx) site, which will help you get started with the fundamentals as well as lead you on to greater heights.

The [Tier 1 lessons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/bb308891.aspx) will take you through Visual Studio Express, and get you writing a simple application.

The [Tier 2 lessons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/bb308734.aspx) introduce some of the core concepts underlying Windows development, including reading and populating forms.

The [Tier 3 lessons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/bb308806.aspx) then introduce some of the concepts around connecting to Databases, including updating them.

The [Aspiring Professional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/beginner/dd547995.aspx) section then points you in the direction of further resources including lots of training materials.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I would work on basic SQL [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations and ADO.NET (particularly the [SqlClient namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx)). Those are the most important concepts for what you're describing, and the ones that will take the most depth of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The important concepts here are going to be [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, event based development, and just the .NET framework in general. You can do all of these things in [Visual Studio 2010 C# Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/) (free), and there are many tutorials around on the net. Need anything more specific?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions, I have found several good tutorials on setting up, connecting, reading and writing to sqlce. A question I have, what process is involved in checking to see if the record is already in the table and if FALSE running additional code to get the data?

Comment: @JRB, you will check if it's in the database by running a query kind of like this SELECT number FROM NumberTable WHERE number = mynumber. That's the SQL query and if you use ADO you will have to execute the query with a SqlCommand object by invoking the ExecuteNonQuery() method on that object. That method returns an int value and if that value is greater than zero, that number was found in the table.